# Meteor-up : deploy does not update app on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, deployment, amazon-ec2, meteor-up

I am hosting a Meteor app on an AWS EC2 instance. I successfully managed to deploy my app twice using Meteor-up (`mup deploy` command).

But after some modification, `mup deploy` still return a perfectly fine message (below) but does nothing, the app is not updated. I tried rebooting the instance after that (and cleaning my own cache) but I still got the old version.

```
Building App Bundle Locally

Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor
[XX.XX.XX.X] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to The Server
[XX.XX.XX.X] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to The Server: SUCCESS
[XX.XX.XX.X] - Pushing the Startup Script
[XX.XX.XX.X] - Pushing the Startup Script: SUCCESS
```

I can connect to the app using `ssh`, but I don't know what to do next. I switched to Meteor 1.4.1 (from Meteor 1.4.0) recently, but I don't think this is related.

Could someone please help me to investigate this issue / provide some possible solutions ?

Edit : here is the log from the `docker info` command. I have two containers running, but deploying does not seem to increase this number, I am not familiar with Docker either.

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 4
Server Version: 1.12.0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 20
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-93-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 992.5 MiB
Name: ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX
ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

**Edit 2 :** The issue seems to be related to some kind of fake positive. Deployment is okay, but the app actually crash on launch and thus rollback to the last version, according to docker logs.

Comment: Can you tell us what you changed in your mup config?

Comment: Hi, I changed nothing in the mup config between the two updates.
I use `dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base'` due to an issue with the default docker image used by mup and Meteor 1.4, could it lead to this issue ?

Comment: Got it. I'm not very familiar with running Meteor in Docker containers, but if that's the only thing you had changed, I'm sure that's a solid place to start looking.

Comment: Okay thanks, do you have any idea on how to investigate this ? For instance, how to tell how many docker instance are running on the EC2 instance or anything else that could help ? I am really far from being a sysadmin ^^

Comment: Sorry, but I have never used Docker or ECS with Meteor before so I'm not really sure where to start. Aren't you able to see the number of running containers in the ECS dashboard in your AWS account?

Comment: There are two containers, one for mongo, and one for meteor. There is also an image for each. I removed two images (`kadirahq/meteord` and `meteorhacks/meteord`) that are not compatible with Meteor 1.4 and that I don't use anymore.
When I deploy my app, something actually happens on the server as I can feel the ssh connection slowing down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the issue. My `settings.json` file had a syntax error (trailing comma), so the app actually crashed on start.

To get this info, I connected to my EC2 instance using ssh. Then I found the container id using `docker ps` and I used the `docker logs MyContainerId` command to get the app logs.
`mup logs` should actually give the same info without the need of an ssh connection to the instance, but there is an open issue about it and it does not work.

The logs told me that `Meteor.settings` was undefined, I simply fixed it.
I opened an issue on Github here https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up/issues/242 , since I think `mup deploy` should have informed me about the crash from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the app path in the configuration file. The path may be different for the one in the configuration file.

Comment: You are talking about `mup.js` ? I set up `meteor.path` to `../`, as the `mup.js` is in the `myapp/.deploy/` folder. When I run `mup deploy`, I am in this `.deploy` folder, so path sound so okay :/ Anyway, a wrong path would give an error message, wouldn't it ?